# Determine if the constructor is called upon the same element in JavaScript Constructor Design Pattern

Tags: javascript, constructor

I've been using constructor pattern like this:

```js
function Class(parameter) {
  this.id = parameter;
}

let testOne = new Class('a');
let testTwo = new Class('a');

console.log(testOne === testTwo);
console.log(testOne == testTwo);
console.log(testOne.id === testTwo.id);
```

As you can see, my first `console.log(testOne === testTwo)` returns `false`. I think that it has to do with the fact that different instances of a `new` constructed objects are always different from one another even if it has the same exact properties. Is there another way to check if two objects constructed with the same exact properties other than checking their unique and identifying properties directly?

Comment: you can always add new things to object, why constructor matters?

Comment: @appleapple Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Not sure if related but might be helpful to read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Internally js has two different approaches to check equality, for
>   primitives (like string) it goes for value comparison and for objects(arrays ,Date object)
>   it goes for reference(That comparison by reference basically checks to
>   see if the objects given refer to the same location in memory.)

Here is an approach to check objects equality by value

```js
function Class(parameter) {
  this.id = parameter;
}

let testOne = new Class('a');
let testTwo = new Class('a');
//console.log(testOne === testTwo);//gives false 
//console.log(testOne == testTwo); // gives false
//
let testThree=testOne;
console.log(testOne === testThree);//gives true (As they both refer to the same instance in memory now)


/// objects equality by value


function isEquivalent(a, b) {
    // Create arrays of property names
    var aProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a);
    var bProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);

    // If number of properties is different,
    // objects are not equivalent
    if (aProps.length != bProps.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < aProps.length; i++) {
        var propName = aProps[i];

        // If values of same property are not equal,
        // objects are not equivalent
        if (a[propName] !== b[propName]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // If we made it this far, objects
    // are considered equivalent
    return true;
}

// Outputs: true
console.log(isEquivalent(testOne, testTwo));
```

If you feel that method is long and complicated you can try some libraries like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual) it has built in functions for such tasks.

```js
function Class(parameter) {
  this.id = parameter;
}

let testOne = new Class('a');
let testTwo = new Class('a');


console.log(_.isEqual(testOne, testTwo));
// => true
 
console.log(testOne === testTwo);
// => false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see. So basically, checking for properties, right? My question was whether it is possible to determine if the two objects are exactly the same other than checking its unique identifying property.

Comment: I guess not ,I have explained in my answer (the reference thing)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which compare two shallow object.

```js
function Class(parameter) {
  this.id = parameter;
}

let testOne = new Class('a');
let testTwo = new Class('a');

function compObj(obj1,obj2){
    if(Object.keys(obj1).length !== Object.keys(obj2).length) return false;
    for(let key in obj1){
        if(obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) return false;
    }
    return true;
} 
console.log(compObj(testOne,testTwo));
```

Comment: OP: *if two objects constructed with the same exact properties*, not if use same constructor.

Comment: I doubt your answer ,the question asks something else

Comment: @appleapple I have fixed the answer please check it.

Comment: What do you mean by *shallow object*? Your code basically checks for all the properties, right? I'd like to avoid the checking of properties if at all possible.